# Ajax Image Upload Notice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i think i sleep already, cant find my mistake. Thanks for your advance for this short post and for your help.

My Javascript

```
$("#avatarImage").change(function() {
    $("#avatar").html('<img src="assets/images/loader.gif" alt="">');
    $.post( 'ajax/avatarUpload.php', function( data ) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

My Form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="ajax/avatarUpload.php" id="avatarUpload">
    <span class="btn btn-teal btn-file btn-sm"><span class="fileupload-new"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span><span class="fileupload-exists"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>
        <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatarImage">
    </span>
</form>
```

My PHP Code

```
$file_up_size = $_FILES['avatar']['size'];
$file_name = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$add = '../assets/images/avatars/' . $file_name;

if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $add)){
    echo 'FEHLER';  
} else {
    //database crap
}
```

My Error(s)

```
Notice:  Undefined index: avatar in ...
```

Thanks for your help, i am blind this evening.

Comment: Hard to say but I tend to think it's your JS that is failing. You may also want to use this instead 
`$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['avatar']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$file_up_size = $_FILES['avatar']['size'];
$file_name = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$add = '../assets/images/avatars/' . $file_name. "." .$ext;

$add = '../assets/images/avatars/' . $file_name;` - otherwise, you're not going to get the right file extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$.post()` is posting to the form but it is not supplying any data to that form. This is causing `undefined index: avatar` because your `post` doesn't include an index of `avatar` within the `files` array. To resolve this, pass along the image in your `POST` by constructing a `FormData` object. Further, the ajax wrapper `$.post()` doesn't allow you to set certain options, and therefore we need to unwrap it and use `$.ajax()` instead.

```
$("#avatarImage").change(function() {
    $("#avatar").html('<img src="assets/images/loader.gif" alt="">');
    var fd = new FormData()
    fd.append('avatar', $('#avatarImage')[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/avatarUpload.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: fd,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: still getting the same errors and this amazing link avatarUpload.php?[object%20FormData]

Comment: @Webice the javacsript is not the issue then, add error reporting to your php script until you find the hiccup, such as what Fred-ii- mentioned above in the comments.

Comment: @Webice I'm sorry, I ommitted something in my code, please check again. I forgot to add `type: 'POST',` to the `$.ajax()`.

Comment: JS isn't my strong point, far from it. PHP/SQL, ah now that's another story ;) - Glad you were able to help out the OP. +1 *cheers*

Comment: `FormData` [only works in IE10+](http://caniuse.com/#search=formdata). About *half* of all IE users won't be able to run this code.

Comment: @amphetamachine Yep, it's true. It's a fair point to make. :)